# Hbase composite key and aggregated rows

Tags: hbase

Is that possible to have a composite key and then coreponding aggregate rows in habse

supose my composite key for the table is uderID,chargingID,

the other two columns are ..value, kids..but the kids columns is based on just userid

somethink like below:

|usr1,|chg1,|20$,|kid1,kid2|

|usr1,|chg2,|30$,|        |

usr2,|chag1,|50$,| usr2| kid1,kid4,kid3|

Answer (score 0):

In HBase, each column is on its own. They are just hooked together by row key. We should not see HBase as row level. Its actually a columnar format.

So coming back to composite key - how you maintain the relation between row key and columns is up to you. The design will only help you to search better based on row key. This is important as HBase performs best when searched with row key and performance gradually goes down as you start using column values9which is filters in Hbase].